# How to add/display/manage private videos that only a specific member group can access?

Tags: video, channel-videos

I've used DevDemon Channel Videos plugin successful in the past, but this time the videos will need to be "private" so I can't host them on Youtube or Vimeo. I'm trying to brainstorm the best way to set this section up so it's easy for the client to add videos. The videos need to only be accessible to a certain member group.

I know if I want to host the videos on the site server that I need like 3 different video file types in order to display the video on different browsers (how annoying!). This doesn't sound very client friendly. Not as friendly as using a video service like Youtube that automatically converts video and works in all browsers. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If you have a vimeo plus account, you can set the video as private and only allow the embedding on one site (yours). Pretty sure youtube has similar options (although not tested). This has worked very well for us.
2. If you want to host videos on site and use HTML5 / Flash playback I recommend [mediaelements.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/).

Making the videos accessible to a single member group can be done easily with conditionals like

```
{if member_group == "2"}
display video embed code
{/if}
```

If you want to go vanilla and not use add-ons, a simple text field where client has to enter the video ID on Vimeo is enough. Template can handle the embed code. WIth that setup, you can also combine youtube / vimeo pretty easily by adding another custom field (drop down / radio group / p&T pill) alowing the user to select the service they uploaded the video on.

Comment: Jerome, Vimeo Plus is very interesting and sounds exactly like what I need. I'll have to look into YouTube has the same "domain level privacy" feature. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would just setup a video channel with DevDemon's Channel Video fieldtype so the client can post videos after uploading them to YouTube.

Then in the video template just use a conditional to show/hide videos to a certain field group:

```
{if member_group == "5"}
   show video 
{if:else}
   hide video
{/if}
```

Comment: Thanks Siebird, I will probably use Channel Videos as I've had success with it in the past. With Jerome's info about Vimeo Plus I think I have a plan. Thanks!